# Visual Studio Breakpoints window: What does the TreeView show?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

Usually when using breakpoints in Visual Studio (2008 in this example), I just see a flat list. Sometimes though, I get a tree-view for each breakpoint, as shown below (there are 26 child nodes of the expanded node). All the tree nodes refer to the same line of code, and all the optional columns display the same data for each node. I guess that they're possibly to do with threads, but what is the use of these and what do they actually show? And if they are of some use, how are you supposed to distinguish between them?

[Breakpoints window http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2244242173.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2244242173.png)

Comment: It's usually multiple instantiations of the same code - I was going to say usually when you have a generic base class, but I can't make that work myself now. Or at least that was the explanation when I was programming with C++ and ATL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, it seems to relate to the AppDomains in the process being debugged. If I attach WinDbg to the process, load SOS.dll and run `!DumpDomain`, I can see 26 AppDomains, corresponding to the 26 tree nodes in the question. It would be nice if there was a column in the Breakpoints window that would distinguish between these!

Answer (score 3):

These are called Child Breakpoints, are sparsely documented ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b98cwcyw(v=vs.100).aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02ckd1z7(VS.71).aspx#vctskbreakpointswindowchildbreakpoints)) and are generally rather buggy.

Empirically, for native code child breakpoints are formed:

1. For inlined functions, instantiated multiple times,
2. For template functions, instantiated multiple times,
3. In static libraries that are linked against multiple DLLs in the debugged process[es],
4. Whenever the debugging engine feels bored.   Seriously, most of them seem outright bogus.